# ¿Cómo soluciono el error IndexError: list index out of range?

Tags: python

Estoy creando un programa de trackeo y al parecer el codigo funciona bien pero el problema es que depende del nombre cambia y da tal error

**Este es mi codigo:**

```
# 1. Descargar HTML y buscar accountID
import requests
import re

#Agrego la participación del usuario
name = input("Ingresa tu ID -> ")
part1 = "https://fortnitetracker.com/profile/all/"
part = "/competitive"
link = part1 + name + part

r = requests.get(link)
uid = re.search(r'"accountId": "([0-9a-f-]+)"', r.text).group(1)

# 2. Acceder a la API y obtener JSON con estadísticas
r = requests.get(f"https://fortnitetracker.com/api/v0/profile/{uid}/stats?season=16&isCompetitive=true")
data = r.json()

stats = data[2]["stats"]["all"]

for e in stats:
  print(f"{e['metadata']['name']:>16s}: {e['displayValue']}")
```

**Este es el error**:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**¿Por que no busco en google o youtube si es un tema común?**
He buscado por eso dos medios y los videos que he encontrado han sido de ninguna ayuda ya que son distintos casos.

Espero de su ayuda, muchas gracias

Comment: Faltan los datos (ID) para probar el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**La solución sería:**

Cambiar la linea de

```
stats = data[2]["stats"]["all"]
```

Por:

```
stats = data[-1]["stats"]["all"]
```

**Muchas gracias a los que invirtieron tiempo con mi problema**

Answer (score 1):

¿Por qué buscas el elemento `2` de la respuesta `data`? El *IndexError* te dice justamente eso, el índice `2` no existe. La respuesta debe ser un json (no una lista), y sus elementos se pueden acceder por nombre.

Si pones un `print(data)` justo antes de declarar `stats` debes poder ver el json, y de seguro verás que no hay ningún elemento con el *key* `2`.

Comment: Entonces como haría ahí para que imprima lo mismo y no me de el error

Comment: Añade la línea `print(data)` y comenta de el código que le sigue. Así puedes ver el contenido de la variable sin causar el error.